# Alias containing space in SQL using AS400 database

Tags: c#, sql, alias, ibm-midrange

I have an SQL statement and I would like to have an alias with a space.
For example:

```
SELECT item as Alternate Item from Items;
```

I tried different syntaxes but it fails.

```
SELECT item as "Alternate Item" from Items;
SELECT item as [Alternate Item] from Items;
SELECT item as {Alternate Item} from Items;
```

It works fine if I change the alias to Alternate for example which doesn't contain spaces.

I am running the sql using the following code:

```
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sql);
command.Connection = con.Connection;
OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);
con.Open();
adapter.Fill(dataset); // At this line I get the following error
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.dll

The database is AS400.

Comment: A workaround might be to rename the column after you've filled the dataset.

Comment: Yes I know, I was wondering if it is possible in AS400 to do it as it is in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of IBM i?

This works fine on 7.1

```
SELECT IBMREQD as "alt name" FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Comment: Since my sql was defined in a variable: string sql ="...", I tried with single quotes and it doesn't work for me.
So I tried: "select Item  as \"ALTERNATE ITEM\" from Items" and it is fine